# How to pass a list from view to a MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a search function in MVC to get matching transactions. When the transactions is loaded a table is populated with the result. This result i want to post to a controller to export the transactions to an Excel file. The problem is when iam posting my view model to my controller the whole view model is empty. I have searched around a lot and its a bunch of different result but i cant get it to work. Here is my code:

**UPDATED**

**View Model:**

```
    public class TransactionsViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public TransactionsViewModel()
        {
            Charges = new List<Transaction>();
            Invoices = new List<Invoices>();
        }

        public List<Transaction> Charges { get; set; }
        public List<Invoices> Invoices { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Telefonnummer")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Personnummer")]
    public string PersonalIdentityNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Ordernummer")]
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Orderbeskrivning")]
    public string OrderDescription { get; set; }

    // A lot of other input format controls

public class Transaction
    {
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public string Msisdn { get; set; }
            public string OrderNo { get; set; }
            public string NetsId { get; set; }
            public string Reference { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public decimal Amount { get; set; }
            public decimal Vat { get; set; }
            public string Merchant { get; set; }
            public decimal Fee { get; set; }
            public string PaymentType { get; set; }
            public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
            public string OrderDescription { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

**View**

```
    <div id="transactionsdiv">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchTransactions", "Transactions", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "merchant-form" }))
    {
        <div class="left-col">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-button">
            <input type="submit" value="Sök" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    }


<div>
    @Html.Partial("ExportFiles")
</div>
```

**ExportFiles**

```
<div id="">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportTransactions", "Transactions", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "merchant-form" }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Exportera" class="btn btn-primary" />
    if (Model.Charges != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Charges.Count; i++)
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="command.Transaction[i].Date" value="@(Model.Charges[i].Date)" />
            <input type="hidden" name="command.Transaction[i].Status" value="@(Model.Charges[i].Status)" />
            <input type="hidden" name="command.Transaction[i].Msisdn" value="@(Model.Charges[i].Msisdn)" />
            <input type="hidden" name="command.Transaction[i].OrderNo" value="@(Model.Charges[i].OrderNo)"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="command.Transaction[i].NetsId" value="@(Model.Charges[i].NetsId)"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="command.Transaction[i].Message" value="@(Model.Charges[i].Message)"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="command.Transaction[i].Amount" value="@(Model.Charges[i].Amount)"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="command.Transaction[i].Reference" value="@(Model.Charges[i].Reference)" />

        }
    }
}
<table id="Transaction" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th class="amount-col">Msisdn</th>
            <th>OrderNo</th>
            <th>Netsreferens</th>
            <th>Beskrivning</th>
            <th class="amount-col">Belopp</th>
            @if (Model.AllowRefund)
            {
                <th>Återköp</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Charges != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Charges.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-col">@Model.Charges[i].Date</td>
                    <td>@Model.Charges[i].Status</td>
                    <td class="amount-col">@Model.Charges[i].Msisdn</td>
                    <td>@Model.Charges[i].OrderNo</td>
                    <td>@Model.Charges[i].NetsId</td>
                    <td>@Model.Charges[i].Message</td>
                    <td class="amount-col">@Model.Charges[i].Amount</td>
                    @if (Model.AllowRefund)
                    {
                        <td>
                            @if (Model.Charges[i].Status == "Completed")
                    {
                                <a href="/Merchants/Refund?chargeId=@(Model.Charges[i].Reference)"><button type="button" class="m-button m-button-main">Återköp<    /button></a>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                            }
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }

        }
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ExportTransactions(TransactionsViewModel command)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Not showing in this example but i am using a partial view for the transactionstable with a mvc form tag around it to post that values to the controller. I have tried to use a for loop instead a for each loop and tried just to insert a Html.editorFor(model => model.Charges) to get the list. But everytime i post the model to the controller the model is EMPTY. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using a `for` loop to make input name to follow the hierarchy of object graph like `TransactionsViewModel.Charges[0].Transaction.PhoneNumber` and check if that make any difference.

Comment: Like i described in the text i have already tried that but did some changes and have have updated my question so you can see my code right now. It was no difference

Comment: You partial view does not generate any form controls so there is nothing to post back. And since there is nothing editable, there is no point having a form. It unclear what you wanting to do.

Comment: Like it said in my question i did not show all of my code. But i want to post  my search result to an mvc controller so i can export that to an excel file but when the post is done the parameters are null in the request. @StephenMuecke

Comment: Your `ExportFiles` view is posting back to `ExportTransactions` which accepts parameter `TransactionsViewModel` which contains only 2 properties, `List<Invoices> Invoices` and `List<Transaction> Charges` The view you have shown does not contain any form controls (`<input>` `<textarea>` or `<select>`), so there is nothing to post back! And nor should it unless your editing something. Just populate the model in the post method again based on your search parameter(s).

Comment: I updated my view model with some of its content so you can see. I dont really understand how you mean i could post that but to the controller. Please explain :) @StephenMuecke

Comment: The only controller method you have shown is `public ActionResult ExportTransactions(TransactionsViewModel command)` and the only view you have shown that posts to that method is `ExportFiles.cshtml`. That form does **NOT** contain any form controls so again i repeat **there is nothing to post back to the controller**

Comment: Okey maybe i misunderstood you but if you look at the answer below and my updated question i have a bunch input form controls that are hidden and i want to send this input in an array to the controller but when the controller method is hit it is null. I want to send the search result in the table back to the controller i dont want to send the input control values back to do another search. Do you get the difference? i dont know if i am reaching out to you @StephenMuecke

Comment: Your creating name attributes which have absolutely no relationship to your model. You don't create inputs like that - its `for (int i = 0; i < Model.Charges.Count; i++) { @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Charges[i].Status)` etc. But why on earth would you degrade your app by sending a whole lot of data to the view and then posting it all back again unchanged, not to mention the security risks. Just get the data from the database again

Comment: Okey i did it after your suggestion and posting the search parameters and doing another search in that controller and everything works fine. My original point was to find a way to not have to do this but if you think about the security you are definitly right so thanks for the heads up. :) @StephenMuecke

Comment: No problem. But why did you accept an incorrect answer (it will not bind to your model) and its misleading to other users?

Comment: Sorry was in a rush. I will post the correct answear! @StephenMuecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am not sure why my answer is misleading. I proposed, and strongly recommended, to perform the search again instead of posting the values. And then, posted a solution for the specific question. My answer binds correctly to the model in the Transactions .ExportTransactions Action. Although, I agree that ´@Html.HiddenFor´ is easier to use and recommended in almost every case. I did not want to assume that the model was exactly the same.

Comment: It does not bind to the model. `TransactionsViewModel` contains a property `List<Transaction> Charges` which means the inputs need to have name attributes which are `name="Charges[0].Date`, `name="Charges[1].Date` etc., not `name="command.Charges[0].Date"`

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form, it will fill the request form data with the values of the input controls inside the form. In your form there are no input controls so nothing is sent.

Sending back to the server a whole list of data that you just got from it seems like a lot of overhead to me. I would just send back the search parameters and the server can perform the search again and return the Excel you need to build. Or, if your search is too slow to perform it again, a list of ids of the charges (or invoices) to lookup in the database should be enough.

In any case, what you need to send back to the server (as form parameters) have to be in the form. The easiest way is to add a hidden input for each field you need to send back. In this case you are sending an array of objects so you will have to [create proper names](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) of the inputs.

Something like this should do the trick:

**ExportFiles**

```
<div id="">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportTransactions", "Transactions", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "merchant-form"}))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Exportera" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    @if (Model.Charges != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Charges.Count; i++)
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="command.Charges[@(i)].Date" value="@Model.Charges[i].Date" />
            <input type="hidden" name="command.Charges[@(i)].Status" value="@Model.Charges[i].Status" />
            <input type="hidden" name="command.Charges[@(i)].Msisdn" value="@Model.Charges[i].Msisdn" />
            <input type="hidden" name="command.Charges[@(i)].OrderNo" value="@Model.Charges[i].OrderNo" />

            @* All the other properties of your objects that you need to send to the server on post. You get the idea... *@
        }
    }
}
<table id="Transaction" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th class="amount-col">Msisdn</th>
        <th>OrderNo</th>
        <th>Netsreferens</th>
        <th>Beskrivning</th>
        <th class="amount-col">Belopp</th>
        @if (Model.AllowRefund)
        {
            <th>Återköp</th>
        }
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if (Model.Charges != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Charges.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="text-col">@Model.Charges[i].Date</td>
                <td>@Model.Charges[i].Status</td>
                <td class="amount-col">@Model.Charges[i].Msisdn</td>
                <td>@Model.Charges[i].OrderNo</td>
                <td>@Model.Charges[i].NetsId</td>
                <td>@Model.Charges[i].Message</td>
                <td class="amount-col">@Model.Charges[i].Amount</td>
                @if (Model.AllowRefund)
                {
                    <td>
                        @if (Model.Charges[i].Status == "Completed")
                        {
                            <a href="/Merchants/Refund?chargeId=@(Model.Charges[i].Reference)"><button type="button" class="m-button m-button-main">Återköp<    /button></a>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <div>&nbsp;</div>
                        }
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }

    }
    }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

The table that shows the data has nothing to do with the form that will be posted to the server so it is perfectly fine outside of it.

Keep in mind that the hidden inputs are just that, inputs hidden from the user, but they are not readonly so any user with enough knowledge can change them before sending to the server and you will produce an excel with incorrect data. Because of this, I will strongly recommend performing the search again using the original parameters before creating the Excel.

Comment: Okey so i did the changes that you suggested and i have tried to have an array as input parameter type to control the posting parameters. But when the controller method is hit the array is empty. I have read the article that you suggested and have tried that but something is wrong that i cant figure out. Is it something that it is a partial view and the Transactionspartialview is posting to a controller of type Transactionsviewmodel? Sorry if i am confusing you!

Comment: @AndreasJangefalk awe man i know your trying but i just don't think your getting it, but don't worry i was there two at some point, anyway to be helpful... when i was doing this stuff... i used from "FormCollection form" in the controller..... this is helpful for understanding what the controller was able to pick up. so use "public ActionResult ExportTransactions(TransactionsViewModel command, FormCollection form)" and inspect form as you tweak your code. The other guys in there are giving good advice.

Comment: A little late as I have just read that you went for the search again solution. For sure a better solution. But from the code you show in your updated question I see that you are assigning the name of the hidden input as name="command.Transaction[i].Date", and it should be name="command.Transaction[@(i)].Date" in order to write the value of the i variable and not the character 'i'.